# Optional parameters in BizTalk RESTservices

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013

I have a requirement to pass the Query Strings supplied to my BizTalk Rest endpoint to a Third Party url. I have configured this in the BtsUrlMapping.

```
 <BtsHttpUrlMapping> 
<Operation Method='GET' Url='?State={sid}&City={cid}' />
 </BtsHttpUrlMapping>
```

I need help to remove the empty parameters from the URL and only show the parameters that contain values.

**Instead of** ?State=''&City=Test **Send only** ?City=Test

Comment: Use an expression shape and a variable. In the expression shape, you can do the validations to decide which query parameters you add and build the string variable using concat after each check. Also,make sure to escape the '&' by &amp;

Comment: Thanks.This is an existing application and does not have an orchestration.Send port filtering is enabled based on Operation Name.Please help me understand how to achieve in this scenario.

Comment: Sorry, I just assumed it used an orchestrations, my bad. Can you not just set the multiple variants in your BtsHttpUrlMapping? So one for Url='?State={sid}&City={cid}', one for Url='?State={sid}' and one for Url='?City={cid}' ? I haven't tried this without an orchestration before.

Comment: I have around 14 request params,so looking for any custom solution,otherwise I might have to add the orch

Answer (score 0):

your only choice I think is to make a URL rewrite on IIS.

have a look on this link :

[Creating Rewrite Rules for the URL Rewrite Module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module)